# What's the architecture for a service with mobile apps & web app, like Instagram when they started?

Tags: ios, mobile, architecture, instagram

If you were building a service like Instagram, when you need
-a web app
-android app
-ios app
How do you make the architecture for this to give enough flexibility to add another mobile system and keep the code as DRY possible? Do you have books to recommend about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to allow the server to support a wide range of client plattforms, I would make all client apps communicate with the server with the same protocol, so that the plattform the client runs on doesn't matter for the server. In an ideal case this would allow to add a new plattform without changing anything on the server-side

XmlHttpRequest is a good common denominator.